# Image spilling outside div

Tags: html, css

I have an image animating from right to left... The image is 6000px wide to give a longer duration to the animation. I put the image (clouds-layer-2.png) in a div (layer-2-container) and used the following CSS hoping that the image wouldn't spill over the div creating a horizontal scroll. But unfortunately it's not working and I have 6000px worth of horizontal scroll.

```
.layer-2-container {
width: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
z-index: 2;
}
```

This can be viewed at http://www.mike-griffin.com/testing. If you use CMD/CTRL+A to select all you'll be able to see the clouds better, if that helps.

I'll also paste all the code below.

-HTML-

```
    <section class="home-section">

    <div class="navigation">
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div><!--navigation-->

    <div class="creative-designer">
    <h2>| Heading one |</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="home-section-layers">

    <img class="layer-1" src="img/white-M-layer-3.jpg" width="" height="">

    <div class="layer-2-container">
    <img class="layer-2" src="img/clouds-layer-2.png" width="" height="">
    </div><!--layer-2-container-->
    </div><!--home-section-layers-->

    </section><!--home-section-->


    </div><!--container-->
```

-CSS-

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}

.home-section {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
}

.layer-1 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
/*margin-top: -10%;*/
z-index: 1;

}

.layer-2-container {
width: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
z-index: 2;
}

.layer-2 {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: auto;
height: auto;
top: 0;
}

.creative-designer {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
color: #666;
margin-top: 40%;
}

.navigation {
color: #0C98D6;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
top: 0px;
}

.navigation ul {
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
padding-right: 5%;
float: right;
}

.navigation ul li {
float: right;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Thank you for any help at all.

Comment: The link isn't working, can you update it or put it on jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: Sorry about the link... was in the middle of the jsfiddle and the question was answered. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Mike the testing site seems to be down. If you put it back up I may be able to help.

Comment: If you want to copy and paste the link its [http://mike-griffin.com/testing/ The link above doesn't seem to be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of Stack Overflow, I'm answering your question exactly.

```
.home-section {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I want to stress, though, that this site is *really* heavy, and you should code it such that there aren't going to be load issues on mobile. You can split the clouds in half, and/or use an SVG (the M should also be SVG). Additionally, your clouds are going to be overlapping content should you decide to add stuff on the sides, so you might want to set a border-radius to make the circle crop out the clouds.

Just suggestions, but hope they help!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! It's always something so simple! Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. I take it you're a practiced graphic designer because your site looks beautiful!

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions a lot. I might be wrong but SVG images aren't supported in IE 8 and previous? Does this cause more hassle than it's worth when making the site cross browser compatible or is there an easy enough work around? You're also very right regarding the clouds, that image needs to be cut at least in half. Regarding that being an SVG, does SVG support transparency? Oh and yes a graphic designer at heart. Thank your for your suggestions and kind words.

Comment: Absolutely. Clouds will be pretty hard to do as an SVG. Make your M logo (either SVG or transparent PNG) and crop it, you can put it in front of a white div and then it'll be a LOT lighter. 9+ supports SVG I believe but check caniuse.com for browser support. Google and most other companies support 8+. If you think your audience is going to include lots of old people, worry about IE. Otherwise I wouldn't worry about anything below 10. You can also set fallbacks for SVG to PNG. 10+ will auto update! With the clouds, just make them 1x height and 2-3x wide as the M and loop it.

Comment: I've started implementing your suggestions and it's cut out a lot of the weight. Thank you again, everyday is a school day. I've chopped the clouds, could probably chop em a bit more. You able to help with looping of the animation by any chance? been trying different things but can't get it to work. I posted a question about it but it hasn't been answered just yet. Thank you again, I'm very grateful for your input.

Comment: Never done a loop like that haha. I'm prototyping something at work tomorrow so when I'm back in some js I'll take a stab haha

Comment: I have this thing all set. Pure CSS3 animations. No js required. What's your email?

Comment: Oh cool, Thanks. My E-mail is michaelgriffin87@me.com - Is there benefits to using CSS over JS? Just curious. Thanks again!

Comment: It's lighter and easier to maintain.